# Understanding the phrase "function on $L^2$ in the sense of distributions"

Tags: distribution-theory, laplacian

[image]

Hello. The image corresponds to the book of functional analysis volume II by barry simon. I know that any function $f$ in $L^p$ can be identified with a tempered distribution $T_f$ defined by $T_f \varphi=\int f\varphi,\quad \varphi$ test function but what does it mean that $\Delta \varphi \in L^2$ in the sense of distributions? does it mean that $T_{\Delta u}\in L^2$ (in the classical sense)? thank you.

Comment: It should mean that $\Delta\varphi$ (seen as distribution) coincides with $T_f$ for some function $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: The distributional derivatives of $\varphi \in L^2$ are well-defined, that's the meaning of $\Delta \varphi$, a distribution, and you can ask if there is a $L^2$ function that is equal to it as a distribution.

Comment: I understand that $(\Delta u, \varphi)=(u,\Delta \varphi),\, \varphi$ test function but I don't quite understand the fact that $\Delta u$ is in $L^2$ distributionally